# trying to find property values in a collection using reflection

Tags: c#

Was hoping for for al little assistance. I am passing a collection that...for example contains an instance of a property name and value.

```
searchLookups.Add(new SearchLookup() { SearchLookupName = "pernr", SearchLookupValue = 1022343 });
```

Now I want to check in a different collection if the same same property name exists and if it does I want the add these values to a collection of the same type.

```
List<StaffMember> searchedMembers = new List<StaffMember>();
```

this is the collection I am checking if the propert name and value exist.

```
foreach (var staffmember in staffMembers)
{
    Type t = staffmember.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
    foreach (var sl in searchLookups)
    {
        if (pi.Where(p => p.Name == sl.SearchLookupName).Count() > 0)
        {

            if (pi.Where(p => p.Name == sl.SearchLookupName).First().GetValue(staffmember) == sl.SearchLookupValue)
            {
                searchedMembers.Add(staffMember);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

as it is at the moment nothing is added to the new collection(searchedMembers) even though there should be some values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because you used `==` to compare your *found* and *control* values. And because `GetValue` returns `object` you're performing reference equality.

Try using `Equals` method instead:

```
if (pi.Where(p => p.Name == sl.SearchLookupName).First().GetValue(staffmember).Equals(sl.SearchLookupValue))
```

btw, you can use `FirstOrDefault()` and `!= null` check to make your code more clear:

```
foreach (var sl in searchLookups)
{
    var prop = pi.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == sl.SearchLookupName);
    if(prop != null && prop.GetValue(staffmember).Equals(s1.SearchLookupValue)
    {
        searchedMembers.Add(staffMember);
    }
}
```